# segmentation fault when converting rxbag to csv

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS fans..

I try to export data from a bagfile using rxbag. After plotting without problems, then I do right click-> export to csv and after naming the file everything crashes with just a seg fault:

Does anybody know why does this happen and how to solve this?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 and rxbag crashes both in ROS electric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61718/segmentation-fault-when-converting-rxbag-to-csv/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not exactly sure why you are getting the segfault. I don't experience this problem on Fuerte.  One potential workaround would be to instead use `rostopic` to produce your csv file.

```
rostopic echo -p -b BAG_NAME TOPIC_NAMES > output.csv
```

will produce a nicely formatted csv file.  I prefer this technique over `rxbag` because it is easier to automate.  More can be [read here.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_echo)

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-04-29**:
it works fine.. thanks @jarvisschultz